# ios TableViewCell Customization issues. Not displaying the customized text

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hi I have an requirement to customize UITableViewCell. Hence I have created a custom class and necessary UI (xib) to support it. For the XIB I have chosen the class as the derived class that I have created. My Problem is when after linking the display labels to the properties and me setting the values at runtime does not display the text desired. Its left as blank. Below is the code snippet.

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *titleRow;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *titleRow;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *subTitleRow;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *otherTextRow;
@end

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MedVaultCell";
    CustomCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (nil == cell){

        //Load custom cell from NIB file
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellHistoryCell" owner:self options:NULL];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        //cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }   

    // get the object
    Weight *currentCellWeight = [_weights objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell...
    UILabel *titleLable = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    titleLable.text = currentCellWeight.customDispText;
    [cell setTitleRow:titleLable];

    cell.titleRow.text = currentCellWeight.display;
    cell.titleRow.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    //cell.textLabel.text = [[_weights objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] customDispText];
    //cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You are putting `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the custom cell class?

Answer (score 0):

First, I hope your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is in your `UITableView` `delegate`, not in your custom cell class.

Secondly, here is the problem:

```
// Configure the cell...
UILabel *titleLable = [[UILabel alloc]init];
titleLable.text = currentCellWeight.customDispText;
[cell setTitleRow:titleLable];
```

In this code you are creating a new label and overriding your IBOutlet label with the new label.  Then you are not displaying the new label.  Instead, change the code to this:

```
// Configure the cell...
cell.titleRow.text = currentCellWeight.customDispText;
```

However, you then reset the `titleRow.text` right after it to `currentCellWeight.display`.

So you need to pick which one of those you want to be the text and set the text to that.  You do not need to create a new label (`UILabel *titleLable = [[UILabel alloc] init];`) because you have already created the label in IB.

Comment: I am sorry I as playing around with code and forgot to comment it. out. I just made the changes like you suggested and it still didn't work. What works is if I try the default


    cell.textLabel.text = currentCellWeight.display;

But this means I am not able to customize the cell the way I need it to be.

Comment: Make sure your cell Identifier is set to "MedVaultCell" and that your cell's Class is set to "CustomCell" and your IBOutlet is properly hooked up.